# Put legend (pgfplots) below the plot

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have a pgfplot where the legend is right to the plot. I create the plot as follows:

```
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmode=log,
    ymode=log,
    width=7cm,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={draw=none}
  ]
```

Now I would like to move the legend down below the plot. So I thought I have just to replace `legend pos=outer north east` by `legend pos=outer south west`. But LaTex does not like this idea: `Choice 'outer south west' unknown in key '/pgfplots/le
gend pos'`. Whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From section 4.8.5 of the manual, you can use  `every axis legend`:

```
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0,0)},
anchor=north east}}
```

Code: (partially from manual )

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
 \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
    at={(0,0)},
    anchor=north east}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,3)};
\legend{$l_1$,$l_2$,$l_3$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead of the `/.append style`, it is possible to use `legend style` as in the following example. It has the same effect.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={
at={(0,0)},
anchor=north east}]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,3)};
\legend{$l_1$,$l_2$,$l_3$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As percusse mentioned in comment, you can fine tune the position by `at={(axis description cs:0,-0.1)}` as in:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={
at={(0,0)},
anchor=north east,at={(axis description cs:0,-0.1)}}]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,3)};
\legend{$l_1$,$l_2$,$l_3$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I try your solution and put `anchor=north west`, its exactly what I want but the x-axis labels are hidden by the legend. Any proposal how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: @ThomasWitkowski Use `anchor=north west,at={( xticklabel cs:1)}` or `anchor=north west,at={(axis description cs:1.05,-0.05)}`

Comment: If anyone else checks this, one can center the legend box below the plot via `anchor=north,at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.18)},`. The `-0.18` should suffice for the y-offset due to the `xlabel`, at least it does in my case. I'd also recommend to use multiple legend columns with `legend columns={..insert number here}` then.

Comment: @henry: Thanks so much for your comment, that was exactly what I came looking for. For the record: An effective way to get the same effect without manually adjusting is to use `legend to name` and referring to it directly after the picture.