# fix position legend in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, legend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Put legend (pgfplots) below the plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83328/put-legend-pgfplots-below-the-plot)

I'm trying to set correctly the right position of the legend of my plot. I would have the legend just bottom right of my plot. Any idea? Using this code I got error

```
legend style={
cells={anchor=south},
legend pos=outer south east,
},
```