# How to put legend below the chart?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have the following code that produces a line chart:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    use units,
    cycle list name=exotic, %This defines the color. It produces nicer colors
        width=15cm, height=8cm,     % size of the image
        grid = major,
        grid style={dashed, gray!30},
        %xmode=log,log basis x=10,
        %ymode=log,log basis y=10,
        xmin=0,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
        ymin=0,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
        %/pgfplots/xtick={0,5,...,60}, % make steps of length 5
        %extra x ticks={23},
        %extra y ticks={0.507297},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        ylabel=Time,
        xlabel=Number of Datapoints (n),
        y unit=s,y unit prefix=m,
        tick align=outside]

      % import the correct data from a CSV file
      \addplot table [col sep=comma,trim cells=true,y=Best Case (Ascending)] {datasets/time_mergesort.txt};
          \addplot table [col sep=comma,trim cells=true,y=Average Case (Random)] {datasets/time_mergesort.txt};
                    \addplot table [col sep=comma,trim cells=true,y=Worst Case (Descending)] {datasets/time_mergesort.txt};
                     \legend{Ascending,Random,Descending}
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Mergesort Run Time for Sorting Random Data}
    \label{fig:merge_sort_from_csv}
\end{figure}
```

And at the moment the legend appears on the chart on the upper right corner. I need to move that below the chart, or even to leave that on the chart but to move that on the upper left corner.

I have tried the solution mentioned at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83328/put-legend-pgfplots-below-the-plot), but it did not work for me.

How can I move the axis in a different position?

Comment: For the upper left corner: `legend pos=north west`. See the manual (Section 4.9.5) for outer legend positions. It is _much_ easier for others to help you if you provide minimal but complete examples. In this sample you have many lines of unrelated options that have nothing to do with the question. But you also leave out `\documentclass{<...>}` and package loading, requiring us to type extra things to produce a document. Please see our info on [minimal working examples (MWEs)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @PaulGessler Do you want to answer, or close as unclear?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`pgfplots` defines several shortcut `legend pos` settings, as defined in Section 4.9.5 of its [manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots); here you could choose `legend pos=north west` or `legend pos=outer north east`, which is currently the only pre-defined legend position outside the axis box.

If you want to place it in any other location, the `legend pos` keys are just shorthand for

```
legend style={at={(<x>,<y>)},anchor=<name>}
```

where `<x>` and `<y>` are in terms of the `rel axis cs` (ranges from 0 to 1 over the width and height of the axis box.

Here are a few possibilities:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north west]
  \addplot {x};
  \addlegendentry{$x$}
  \addplot {x^2};
  \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
  \addplot {x};
  \addlegendentry{$x$}
  \addplot {x^2};
  \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north}]
  \addplot {x};
  \addlegendentry{$x$}
  \addplot {x^2};
  \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### More general solution prompted by a comment

The original answer focused on cases where there was no `xlabel`. If there is one, and you want the legend to appear below the `xlabel`, you could manually adjust the legend's x- and y- coordinates in the `at` key value. But if the size of your label or the proportions of the axis change, the required coordinates may also change.

So IMHO a better way is to use a named legend. This allows you to print the legend separately after the current axis is closed and its size/bounding box is known. See section 4.9.7 of the [current `pgfplots` manual](https://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) for full details. It could be argued that this is better than my original `at={(<x>,<y>)}` solution even in cases where there is no `xlabel`, because this avoids needing to come up with magic numbers for the coordinates.

Adapting the examples above, this new method would look something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend to name=myfancyname,xlabel={Test}]
  \addplot {x};
  \addlegendentry{$x$}
  \addplot {x^2};
  \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
\end{axis}
\node[anchor=north] at (current axis.below south) {\ref{myfancyname}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image]

Comment: What if I have an xlabel below the lowest plot?

Comment: @mcmuffin6o good question, that lead me to come up with a more generalized answer than my original. Updates to the answer coming shortly.

Comment: Holy moly! That really is quite nice. I'm a noob to pgfplots, so concise examples such as yours are incredibly helpful.