# What is the best way to plot coordinates in Latex?

Tags: plot

I need to plot some points in a graph; just a simple list of x and y values and then connect them with line segments. Currently, I am graphing it in excel and importing the image into latex and it doesn't look good. Is there any way to plot coordinates just using latex?

Comment: There's [pgfplots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)

Comment: Or you can use `PSTricks`. For my opinion is very easy to utilize.

Comment: It depends on: if you prefer the classical LaTeX and compile a DVI-file, PStricks is suited better.  If you prefer the modern way and run pdfLaTeX or similar compilers, I advise to use TikZ and PGF.  PSTricks is based on PostScript, which works well with DVI, but not with PDF.  On the other hand, TikZ and PGF work well with PDF but not DVI and PostScript.  If you are an absolute beginner, you won't care, if you have to learn the one or the other from scratch.  Therefore, my suggestion would be to learn pgfplots.

Comment: You may want to have a lookt at this example: http://d.xav.free.fr/tikz/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Data points can be directly entered using the `data` command from the `datavisualization` library. The same applies if you have the function instead of the data points. Here are some examples adapted from the Ti*k*Z-PGF manual:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data {
       x, y
    -1.5, 2.25
      -1, 1
     -.5, .25
       0, 0
      .5, .25
       1, 1
     1.5, 2.25
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the axes style to scientific, e.g., can give a different look:

```
\datavisualization [scientific axes, all axes={grid}, visualize as smooth line]
```

[image]

Also, if you have the function at hand, this can be quite easy:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data [format=function] {
      var x : interval [-1.5:1.5] samples 7;
      func y = \value x*\value x;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

with the same result as the data points entry:

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Here is an example using `pgfplots`. The data can also be read from a `csv` file or can be computed using formulas.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {
      (1,  1)
      (2,  4)
      (3,  9)
      (4, 16)
      (5, 25)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can actually read any txt file, even some generated by laboratory equipment, isn't?

Comment: @G.Bay It depends what you mean by "any" text file. The data must be structured: one data set per line, the values separated by a space or some other unique character. But this is usually how data is made available.

Comment: @gernot is it possible to show how to put two such plots side by side?

Comment: @AlexanderCska What exactly do you mean by side by side? Have you tried the code above, but doubling the `tikzpicture`, i.e., using `\begin{tikzpicture}....\end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture}....\end{tikzpicture}`? There are many other ways of arranging plots, e.g. by using them as entries of a `tabular` environment or as `subfigures` (if you want to have captions and labels). If this comment doesn't help, please open a new question with a description of what you want to achieve,

Comment: @gernot thank you for your reply. My idea was to put two pictures on the same line (side by side).

Comment: Is it possible to add legend to them?

Comment: @alper I'm pretty sure the answer is yes. What type of legend are you thinking of? See e.g. [Put legend below the plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83328/110998). If you need a different legend, please post a question with more details.

Answer (score 9):

Here a small example created with `PSTricks` rather with `TikZ`. Still I do not understand why many users are already leaving this opportunity to build graphics with `PSTricks`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\psset{algebraic,arrows=->}
\def\f{x^2}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(5,5)
    \psaxes[linewidth=.5pt,linecolor=darkgray](0,0)(-4,-1)(3,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[linecolor=magenta]{-5}{5}{\f}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-30,PointNameSep=15pt,PointName={{\scriptstyle(0,.5)},{\scriptstyle(1,f(2))}}]
            (0,0.5){F}(*1 {\f(x)}){A}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know some about R, knitr is a good option:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F, fig.cap="One simple plot.", dev='tikz'>>=
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), y= c(1,2,4,8,16,32,64))
plot(df, pch=16, col="red")
lines(df$x,df$y, col="red", lwd=3)
@
\end{document}
```